# JavaFX System.currentTimeMillis() + Task

Tags: timer, javafx, task

I'm currently doing some GUI with a few animations. I ended up coding a color change of a label by myself. For this I implemented the following task:

```
Task tk= new Task() {
            @Override protected Void call() throws Exception
            {
                colorAnimation=true;
                boolean red = true;
                long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long waitTime= 1000;
                nome.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
                main: while(colorAnimation)
                {
                    while(System.currentTimeMillis() < waitTime+ timer)
                    {
                        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-timer);
                        if(!colorAnimation)
                            break main;
                    }
                    timer=System.currentTimeMillis();

                    red=!red;
                    if(red)
                    {
                        nome.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
                        waitTime=1000;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        nome.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
                        waitTime=500;
                    }
                }
                nome.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
                return null;
            }
        };
        Thread t = new Thread(tk);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
```

The function above should initialize the label color in red, wait 1 second, change it to black, wait half a second and change it to red again, repeating this process until colorAnimation is turned off (declared as volatile). The problem is that the function gets stucked inside the second while, and printing to the console the waiting time (System.currentTimeMillis()-timer) gets stucked at 982. If I change the initial waiting time to 500, then the printed waiting time gets stucked at 469. I really have no clue what is happening.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, your code "works" for me, so I can't explain why you are seeing the effects you are seeing.

You shouldn't use this, though. It violates one of the rules of JavaFX: you should not access the state of the scene graph from outside the JavaFX Application Thread. (See, for example, the section on [Threading in the `Application` Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html).) It may be that you are getting an exception thrown when you try to execute the `setStyle(...)` call, causing the thread to terminate; that may explain the behavior you are seeing. (However, this doesn't seem to happen on my system.)

Additionally, your code is very complex and will be hard to maintain. There are higher level APIs designed for this kind of functionality, such as [`Timeline`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html). You should use these APIs to simplify your code and to avoid threading errors.

For example:

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ColorAnimationTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Label nome = new Label("Hello");

        // This chunk of code replaces your entire thread/task code
        Timeline animation = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), 
                        event -> nome.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;")),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1500),
                        event -> nome.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black")));

        animation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        animation.play();

        // Button to stop/start the animation:
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            if (animation.getStatus() == Animation.Status.RUNNING) {
                animation.stop();
            } else {
                animation.play();
            }
        });

        // change text of button approprite to animation state:
        button.textProperty().bind(Bindings
                .when(animation.statusProperty().isEqualTo(Animation.Status.RUNNING))
                .then("Stop")
                .otherwise("Start"));

        VBox root = new VBox(10, nome, button);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 100);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and for the trick. I'm seeing the code and I'm wondering if that works. My questiuon lies on the duration you set for the red color as well as the black color. As far as I'm understanding, that code will make the color change to red every second and will change it to black every 1,5 second. Will there be a problem at the second number three? On my understanding there will, as both events will try to change the color at the same time. Am I correct?

Comment: Why don't you run it?  Then read the java docs for the various method calls to see what it does.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not currently on desktop computer so I cannot try that out now, but I surely will as soons as I'm able.